# Rotating a cylinder distorts it

Tags: animation

When a cylinder is rotated, it is distorted and does not rotate cleanly.

The scale, position, and rotation values of the cylinder are set to 0 or 1.

The origin is also set to be the center of the cylinder.

What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: create a new cylinder without textures and rotate it. same problem?

Comment: The bug does not occur in the new cylinder.

Comment: Then it sounds like your cylinder isn't actually a perfect cylinder. Select all the edge rings on the mesh that make the cylinder circular and then use Loop Tools > Circle to even those out. Then `Shift+S` > Origin to Geometry and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Thank you so much...!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is, that your cylinder is not aligned to the axis you are rotating.

If you look from above (7) you can see this clearly:

[image]

Comment: Ohh I don't know why I did not realize that... but thank you so much !

Comment: you are welcome